# Using void pointer to an array

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I was just trying to use a void pointer to an integer array ,I tried to see if i can print the array back by casting it back into int. But it is giving me some random value. Can you tell me where i am going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a[5];
    int x;
    int j;

    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    a[2]=3;
    a[3]=4;

    void *arr=a;

    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        x = *(int *)(arr+j);
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is this:

```
133554432131072512
```

Why is it not pinting elements of array a[] i.e 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: You can improve the output by putting a newline into the format string that prints the numbers: `printf("%d\n", x);`.

Comment: Yupp.I was not concentrating on the formatting because i wrote this to help myself test this functionality for another program.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to cast `arr` *before* adding `j`. Here is a minimal fix:

```
x = *(((int *)arr)+j);
```

but I think it's clearer to write:

```
x = ((int *)arr)[j];
```

Comment: I was wondering why *(int *)(arr+j) is wrong? Can you please explain me?

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri: Please see my answer, but to sum up, it's wrong because you can't add numbers to `void *`, you need to convert the `void *` *first* and then add numbers to it.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing pointer arithmetic on `void *` which is not valid in C.

In GNU C (C with gcc extensions), it is actually permitted and the `sizeof (void)` is considered to be 1.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html

> "addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void
>   and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a
>   void or of a function as 1."

Comment: +1: for pointing out that arithmetic on `void *` is a GCC extension.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not define behaviour for arithmetic of `void *`, so you need to cast your `void *` to another pointer type *first* before doing arithmetic with it.

Some compilers [as an extension] treat pointer arithmetic of `void *` the same as `char *`, so each ‘+1’ will only increase the address by 1, rather than by the size of the pointed-to object. This is not standardised though so you can't rely on this behaviour.

Comment: oh so u mean pointer arithmetic is not applicable for void * pointers. Well i see the point. Thanks for a great explanation.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999. §6.2.5 ¶19 _The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete type that cannot be
completed._ and then in ¶20 it adds _A pointer type may be derived from a function type, an object type, or an incomplete
type ..._ where an incomplete type is clearly not an object type, so you cannot treat `void *` as a pointer to an object type. §6.5.2 The additive operators says _For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type._  So you cannot do arithmetic on `void *`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The behaviour is not defined by the C standard, but it is not explicitly undefined either, and it's usually these areas where C implementations put in such behaviour and call it an extension.

Comment: @dreamlax as mentioned by @JonathanLeffler addition of an integer and an operand of `void *` type is a clear violation of the constraints of the additive operator (6.5.6p3). So it requires a diagnostic and the implementation is free to not translate the program.

Comment: @ouah: I'm not arguing anything here, if anything I'm agreeing with you; I said that some compilers treat it as an extension. What I'm saying is that it is not *undefined behaviour* to use `void *` in arithmetic, I'm saying it is simply not defined at all (i.e. the standard does not define any behaviour for arithmetic involving `void *`). There is a massive difference between undefined behaviour and something that is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

you should not add numbers to void pointers. cast it before. (`x = *((int *)arr+j);`)

When you add number to a pointer, the compiler multiply this number with the size of the type that is pointed, so if you add number to a pointer to wrong type, you will get wrong result.

if I remember correct, add to void* is illegal, but some compilers adds the exact number in bytes (like it is char*).
`