# Create an Int Array from Int Array Address

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers, pthreads

I am currently working my way through threads in C, and I am currently stuck on using my one parameter (an array to be sorted) on thread creation as the array to work with. For an example:

`void* sort(void* param)`

How do I grab param so that it can be used as an int array local variable?

Also to return the sorted array would I just do `return array` on the last line,

and do something like `int sorted_array[] = pthread_create(&tid, &attr, sort, &un_sorted_array)` to capture it?

I'm new to C to any help would be appreciated?  [Using void pointer to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812690/using-void-pointer-to-an-array)  The solution here still gave me an invalid initalizer error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concept of void pointer in C programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming)

Comment: I tried making sense of that link, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: For starters, you should post your entire code.

Comment: `void* merge(void* arg)
{int *arg_ptr[] = (int*) arg;
int arr[] = *arg_ptr;}`  gives me an invaild initializer error

Comment: Try `void* merge(void* arg) { int *arg_ptr = (int*) arg; }`. To get the result you need to call [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

To access your array you can cast `void` pointer to `int` pointer like this

```
void* merge(void* arg) {
    int* a = (int*) arg;
}
```

To return array you simply do

```
return a;
```

where `a` is `int*`. And to get the result from main thread you call [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) with second argument that points to some `int*`.

```
pthread_join(tid, (void*)&b);
```

where `b` is `int* b;`.

To pass argument to thread you need to get address of the first element of the array (it is the same as pointer for this array). Do it like this

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, merge, (void*)&a[0]);
```

where `a` is an array `int a[N];`.

See full example for `pthread` with `int` array as argument and `int*` as return value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 10

void* merge(void* arg) {
    int* arr = (int*) arg;
    int* res = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            res[i] = arr[i] + 1;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid;

    int a[N];
    int* b;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            a[i] = i;
    }

    printf("a = [");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            printf("%3d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, merge, (void*)&a[0]);
    pthread_join(tid, (void*)&b);

    printf("b = [");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            printf("%3d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```